# Separating data in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a database for a DVD rental service (as a school assignment) and have been given data for the genre of the films. The different types of genres (and the rest of the data) were imported from a pre-existing Excel table. The genres are shown below:

[image: Genres]

The problem with this is that I need to have the genres separated (i.e. I can't have Action/Adventure in one field, they must be separated). The purpose of this is so I can search for DVDs based on their genres, and the same DVD may appear for different genres.

I have tried creating another table related by the 'genre' field and have separated the data using the following code:

```
Left$([genre],InStr(1,[genre],"/")-1)
```

This is for finding one of the genres and putting it in a field named 'genre1'. The following finds the other half of the data and puts it in a field named 'genre2':

```
Right$([genre],Len([genre])-InStr(1,[genre],"/"))
```

This does work, however, it gives me a [`#Func!` error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4YCS.jpg).

Is there any way to prevent this error, and also make the DVDs searchable (in a form) based on either of their genres?

Comment: You're going to get an error for every genre that doesn't have a "/" in it. You need to trap for that before using Instr in a calc

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to see your screenshot at the moment, but from what I read :
You should not add fields for each genre combination. I mean : At the moment you have a maximum of 2 genres combination, but if a film come up with 3 genres you will have to add a 3rd field to your table and that's definitely not a good practice.

You should just make a **linking table between** your **Genre** and your **Film** table.

Your **Genre** table should not contain any combination. The combination should come from your linking table :

```
T_FILM (int [ID], txt [name] ...)
T_GENRE(int [ID], txt [genre])
T_FILM_GENRE(int [fk_ID_FILM], int [fk_ID_GENRE])
```

For your error, it is probably due to the fact `InStr(1,[genre],"/")-1` returns -1 when there is no "/" in the string and `Left$` second parameter cant take negative value

Comment: Was going to post the same - basically a many-to-many join between your film table and your genre table (a genre can be allocated to 1 or more films, a film can have 1 or more genres). You can then use a query such as `SELECT T_Film.sName, T_Genre.Genre
FROM (T_Film INNER JOIN T_Film_Genre ON T_Film.ID = T_Film_Genre.ID_Film) INNER JOIN T_Genre ON T_Film_Genre.ID_Genre = T_Genre.ID` to return the data - this will include duplicate film names though.

Comment: Continue from my comment above - you could write a VBA procedure to stick it together: `SELECT DISTINCT sName, ConcatenateText("SELECT Genre FROM Query1 WHERE sName = '" & Query1.sName & "'") FROM Query1` (ConcatenateText being the VBA UDF).